# UX issue with tableview: didHighlightRowAtIndexPath in iOS6

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6

I'm experiencing some strange behavior when using tableviews in iOS6. I see they've added [tableview:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:](http://conix.dyndns.org/ios_6.0/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidHighlightRowAtIndexPath%3a) but it seems it's causing some user experience problem which reveals in inability to select a row(user may be required to touch the row a few times).

When user just scuffs a tableview or tap with a little swipe, row does not get selected anymore(via `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` but `tableview:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:` is called).

Has anyone experienced similar issues and found any workaround? I'm trying to use a flag and then call `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` from `tableview:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath`. Or simply use `tableview:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` for iOS6 and `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for lower versions as a row-selecting callback.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up introducing new method and flags. It seems quite like a clean solution and works both on iOS6 and on lower versions.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (!_isFromHighlight)
    {
        [self selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    _isFromHighlight=NO;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    _isFromHighlight=YES;
}
```